# Issue creating CSP type certificate for use with Microsoft Teams bot

Tags: openssl, microsoft-teams, lets-encrypt, microsoft-graph-teams

I've been trying to get the a realtime media calling bot up and running in Teams. The example I am using is the Microsoft provided [HueBot](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/master/Samples/V1.0Samples/LocalMediaSamples/HueBot).

The setup requires you to provide an SSL certificate so I have got one from letsencrypt for the appropriate domains I am using & installed it into the Windows keystore.

After setting up all the configuration and running it I get the following error:

```
InvalidOperationException:
Cannot access the certificate's private key.
Make sure that the process has enough permissions to access the private key.
Only CSP-stored certificates are supported by the media platform, CNG/KSP certificates are not supported.
```

Looking into the cert using certutil I can see it is indeed a KSP type key (Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider specifically).

How can I convert this certificate to a CSP type key?

I tried the following command to try convert my .pem files from letsencrypt to a pfx with the correct CSP:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey .\privkey.pem -in .\cert.pem -out test4.pfx -CSP "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider"
```

But OpenSSL seems to just completely ignore what is put in the CSP argument, it always generates the Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider cert, and even if I put gibberish in as the argument it doesn't throw any error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the certificate generated by LetsEncrypt is a supported type. They recently changed the default key type to be `ECDSA`. You want to use `RSA` instead.

You can check if this is case by looking at the certificate properties. Click on the Details tab and then check the value of `Public Key`. It should use `RSA (2048 Bits)` not `ECC (256 Bits)`.

If you are using certbot you can use the command `certbot certonly --key-type rsa` to force it to use the correct key type.